Fun tv show around 2 roommates and a waitress
I remember very little so good luck but here goes:
I watched this over 10 years ago, maybe 15 even.
There's a group of at least 2 guys (could be more, pretty sure it's two). The main settings are the bar and the appartment (pretty sure the 2 guys are roommates). I'm pretty sure the girl is a waitress or bartender at the bar. I'm pretty sure we see the skating often (but could be that I remember it as often because it was in the opening or something).
One of the guys reminds me of Willow's boyfriend in Buffy, the other one is blond.  The girl looks a bit like angie in fx special effects. Also pretty sure it's not them in either case as I remember looking at those actors' filmography a year back when trying to find this show and came up with nothing.
I know this is a weird mix of not very accurate information but it's all that remains in my mind from so long ago.
Edit : Small info but the guy that looked like willow's girlfriend was the "cool / calm guy" while the blond guy (more like platine blond) was kinda insane (not like the joker insane but like stupid to the point of doing pretty stupid stuff)

Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Is it Two Guys, a Girl and a Pizza Place ?

I don't know anything more really, i watched it in france but i don't know what country it is from, i assumed american but could be wrong, i remember nothing else really :(

Is is shasta ?
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shasta_(s%C3%A9rie_t%C3%A9l%C3%A9vis%C3%A9e)
I was shown in France in 2000.

Please explain why you think this is movie.

Ok i have zero clue how you managed to find this based on how little i remembered but a quick google image shows that yes it is! Thank you so much it's been itching me for YEARS lol
